# I don't understand this usage of その?

Tags: grammar

> 「テレワーク」は、離れたを示す「ｔｅｌｅ」と働くの「ｗｏｒｋ」を組み合わせた造語で「遠いところで働く」という意味です。
>
> インターネットやパソコンなどＩＴを使って、会社以外の場所で働くことで、自宅で働く「在宅勤務」や勤務先以外のオフィススペースで働く「サテライトオフィス勤務」などが**その代表例**です。([source](https://www3.nhk.or.jp/news/business_tokushu/2018_0821.html?utm_int=news_contents_tokushu_003))

I don't understand the logic behind it? It seems more logical to use それ(replacing テレワーク)の代表例 because the sentence before is about テレワーク and not about (representative) examples.

XやYなどがその代表例です means literally "X and Y are *those* representative examples" but the sentence before is not about examples at all so I don't understand why we would use '*those*'?

I understand that it means that those are prime examples of 「テレワーク」(deducted with the context and the example sentences that I found where その代表例 is used) but I don't understand the structure and the logic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

その doesn't mean "those" but "its" and in this case it indicates that of テレワーク. In short, it's equivalent to それの while それの is less natural than その.